# Blackberry java new notification message

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm using the code below to show notification messages.

```
ReadableListImpl mylist= new ReadableListImpl();
ApplicationMessageFolder folder = null;
                        
ApplicationDescriptor daemonDescr =  ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();                      
ApplicationDescriptor mainDescr = new ApplicationDescriptor(daemonDescr, "Velocity", new String[] {});
                        
ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig config = new ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig(true, true, mainDescr);

    if(ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().getApplicationFolder(0x33c7ce29883abe5fL)==null){
            folder = ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().registerFolder(0x33c7ce29883abe5fL, "Test Folder", new ReadableListImpl(),config );
                 
    }else {
          folder = ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().getApplicationFolder(0x33c7ce29883abe5fL);
            }

DemoMessage msg = new DemoMessage("name", "Subject","Text body",             
System.currentTimeMillis());
mylist.addMessage(msg);
folder.fireElementAdded(msg,true);
```

This works fine, but when I expand the new notification field to see  the new notifications I can see same message under two fields, Messages and Velocity.
[image]

I don't need to show this messages field in home screen but I need to add those messages in to the Messages folder

When I change first boolean variable to false here Messages field disappears but then messages will not added to the Messages folder also

```
  ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig(false, true, mainDescr);
```

Please tell me how can I do that ?? (there are two additional classes demomessage and readblelistimpl if need I can post those codes also)
Thank you!

Comment: any suggestion,,, please help me I'm stuck here

Comment: if u got the answer for this question please help me